# What kind of different alerts can I configure in VS2012 TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Is there a way to compare last check-in with current change and send an email to both the developers in case the previous changes are overridden?
In other words, this is to make sure that the developer has taken the latest version before performing the changes so that the previous changes are not erased due to some other local version used which might not be up to date.

Comment: There will always be a change within a check-in, otherwise it's not going to be allowed at all. With TFS2012 and beyond, the workspace mentality upgraded and the default workspace type when creating a Team Project is "Local Workspace". You should use a Team Project with "Server Workspace" and force user to "Get Latest" within check out. This way, you'll get what you want. About the [Force Get Latest issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385989(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Workspace Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Beytan, what I wanted was to make sure that nobody accidentaly erases previous changes due to their local workspace files. I went through the link and it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a people issue rather than a tool issue. If your developers don't care to follow good practices then you have a bigger issue. Developers should care...

While forcing server workspaces and get latest will mitigate the short term issue you should also look to address the long term dysfunction.

Maybe some software craftsmanship coaching would be in order to increase their understanding of the value of doing things the right way?